# Creating Tables in Node Database hosted in R3 Corda

Tags: corda

How can we create a new table in the existing node database in the Cordapps we write?

Should it be written in the api file?

How do I establish connection to the node database and also use it to retrieve data without getting the JDBC connection string generated in the shell?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**Manually creating the table:**

First, you need to connect to your node's database. Let's assume you are using the node's built-in H2 database and you want to connect to your node on port 10008.

In Corda 3, you can set the node's H2 port in the `Cordform` task:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    directory "./build/nodes"
    ...
    node {
        name "O=MyNode,L=London,C=GB"
        ...
        h2Port 10008
    }
    ...
}
```

Or directly in the node's `node.conf` file:

```
h2port=10008
```

If the node is running locally, you then connect to the node using the latest stable [H2 client](http://www.h2database.com/html/download.html) using the address:

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:10008/node
```

**Creating the table automatically on node start:**

Nodes can host *services* that are initialised on node start-up and run continually on the node. We can write a service that creates the database table on start-up as follows:

```
private val TABLE_NAME = "crypto_values"

@CordaService
class DatabaseService(private val services: ServiceHub) : SingletonSerializeAsToken() {
    companion object {
        val log = loggerFor<DatabaseService>()
    }

    /**
     * Initialises a database table on the node with name TABlE_NAME.
     */
    init {
        val query = """
            create table if not exists $TABLE_NAME(
                token varchar(64),
                value int
            )"""

        val session = services.jdbcSession()
        val preparedStatement = session.prepareStatement(query)

        try {
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate()
        } catch (e: SQLException) {
            log.error(e.message)
            throw e
        } finally {
            preparedStatement.close()
        }

        log.info("Created $TABLE_NAME table.")
    }
}
```

Comment: in which file should i write the service?